# Create a vertical line that overlays all html content and moves across the page over a certain period of time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a calendar timeline in html. I want to create a vertical line that progresses from left to right over time, the line needs to overlay all the html elements. Similar to Google calendar's way of letting you know what time of day you are at.

An example below of what I want:

[image: timeline]

The black line going vertically across is what I want to create in javascript. I want it to be on top of all elements

I'm trying to create this for a university project and I have no clue where to start

So far I have a progress bar element (using twitter bootstrap) and javascript that updates the width % of the progress bar by calculating the % val of currentTime/(end-start)

Comment: U tried? Show u code.

Comment: @LGSon I would love to do that but I'm doing this for a university project. So far I've just implemented a progress bar that just refreshes with a new % value based on calculations of current time/(end-start)

Comment: @YashMorar that is all that the other commenters wanted (if expressed bluntly):  just show us your progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rough example of where to start. You want to look for efficiency now

```js
var vline=$('#vline');
setInterval(function(){
  vline.css('left', parseInt(vline.css('left')) + 1);
}, 50);
```

```css
#vline{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vline"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
position: fixed; 
width: 2px; 
height: 100vh; 
background-color: #222; 
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
z-index: 100
```

Then animate CSS width or javascript the left value